# how to install on vscode the following dependencies sass and react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs

I can't install on vscode the following dependencies sass and react-router-dom
I wrote on the terminal
npm i react-router-dom sass
But that didn't work
there is an error message displayed:
'up to date, audited 1406 packages in 12s

169 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

6 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.'

Comment: The output is clear, the library is already installed and updated. What problem are you having?

Comment: This is not an error mesage,  just a warning. You can proceed or can fix those warnings with `npm audit fix`

Comment: Alejandro thank u but when I look to package.json file. I don't find the dependences that I am trying to install but I find them in the file package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

If the message is 'up to date' it means that you already have installed react-router-dom and sass and you are just updating them every time you run that command.

You can check that by looking in your package.json file (located in your root folder) and see if the dependencies that you are trying to install are in the list.

If the dependencies are in the list you can try to import react-router-dom to see if it works.

To test sass create a file called app.scss, add some content and import the file inside App.js by running the following command -> import "./app.scss"

Comment: thank you stefantut for answering me. I find the dependences that I am trying to install in the file package-lock.json and not in package.json file. Is it OK?

Comment: You could delete package-lock.json and do `npm install`. This should generate a new package-lock.json . After that, you could try to install the dependencies again(router + sass).